# The $d$-dimension extension of Bernoulli Polynomial

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation-theory

It is known that Bernoulli polynomial has the following Fourier expansion:
\begin{equation*}
B_{2n}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2k\pi x)}{k^{2n}}.
\end{equation*}

Is there similar relation in $d$-dimension case? That is, what is the sum of the following series?
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\lambda\in\mathbb{N}_0^d,\lambda\neq 0} \frac{\cos(2\pi \lambda \cdot x)}{\|\lambda\|_2^{2n}},
\end{equation*}
with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: by $\lambda \cdot x$ do you mean inner product?

Comment: Yeah, $\lambda \cdot x$ means inner product, explicitly, $\lambda \cdot x:=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k x_k$.